Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0 Qt
I recently updated to version qt 6.7.2 and decided to build a project for Android. I built this project before for qt 6.7.0, but now I get a build error "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0"
After that I go to the android settings in qt. Qt qt recommended downloading updates for android, which I did. But the error remains. 

I think you need to fix your build.gradle file.
